# Cauchy epsilon inequality and integration by parts

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following:

[image]

I'm a bit confused. Green's first identity seems to be the way to go but I'm getting nothing out of it.
Also, Is there an interpretation to this equation?

Comment: Do you know Young's inequality?

Comment: It should be $\leq$ instead of $=$ in the displayed equation.

Comment: @gerw yes I've seen Young's ineq nut don't see how to use it here

Comment: @MaoWao why do you say that. Can you show it in a clear way?

Comment: Take a simple domain (say $\Omega=(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$) and any function $u\in C_0^2(\bar\Omega)$. Unless you are very unlucky, the identity will nit hold for all $\epsilon>0$, but the inequality $\leq$ does.

Comment: When does equality hold.?